# How to add views inside coordinator layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I want to add a layout and views inside coordinator layout. I am failing to adjust it's position as I want.

[image]

In this I want these today, tomorrow and later buttons are in one linear layout, this should be above recyclerview and the fab button should be anchored to app bar like it should float between appbar and the other layout below.

If I place recyclerview above then fab button gets aligned perfectly, but I want to set this layout in between. Failing to achieve this.

Layout code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parentPanel">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:id="@+id/appbar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center">

            <com.example.siddhi.googletaskmanager.classes.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/b"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="UserName"
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


            </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
            style="@style/FabStyle"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_playlist_add_white_24dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearLayout" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="Today"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="Tomorrow"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="Later"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_settings_white_48dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Also in another layout I want to add the fab button next ,left to the fab menu. But as fab menu has height and weight as match parent I can not align the fab button next to fab menu.

How to do this..?

Main layout code:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.example.siddhi.googletaskmanager"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/parentPanel"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/expandedappbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
                    android:id="@+id/chart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"/>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:paddingTop="30dp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:weightSum="1">


        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
            android:id="@+id/menu1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            app:menu_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"
            app:menu_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
            fab:menu_icon="@drawable/ic_more_horiz_white_24dp"
            fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="end"
            fab:menu_labels_singleLine="true"
            fab:menu_backgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            fab:menu_fab_label="Menu label">

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_playlist_add_white_24dp"
                fab:fab_size="mini"
                fab:fab_label="addList"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent" />

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_list_white_24dp"
                fab:fab_size="mini"
                fab:fab_label="list1"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"/>

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_list_white_24dp"
                fab:fab_size="mini"
                fab:fab_label="list2"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"/>

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_list_white_24dp"
                fab:fab_size="mini"
                fab:fab_label="list3"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"/>

        </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_48dp"
        style="@style/FabStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thank you..